# Replacing the font of a character using a BDF's glyph

Tags: fonts, faces

I am trying to create some custom glyphs inside a BDF font file and want to use these inside Emacs afterwards.
In order to get started I'd like to change one character (I used the greek alpha character) of the current fontset so it uses the glyph of a given BDF font.
But I have problems getting this to working and need a hints...

I tried several BDF font including the font '9x18.bdf' from [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs-fonts.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs-fonts.html).
Inside that bdf-file I replaced the font family name `Fixed` by `kuhn` so I can easily select it in Emacs via the `:family`.
So after setting up the font on my system (Linux Mint) I used

```
(list-fonts (font-spec :family "kuhn"))
```

and the font shows up perfectly. Also directly setting the font via face attributes works - e.g. if the first character of my buffer is an alpha:

```
(add-face-text-property 1 2 '(:family "kuhn"))
```

But trying to replace the font used for alpha via

```
(set-fontset-font t #x3b1 (font-spec :family "kuhn"))
```

nothing happens (also if I replace `t` by `"fontset-default"`). Doing the same e.g. with a different font

```
(set-fontset-font t #x3b1 (font-spec :family "FreeMono"))
```

works fine and all alphas will get replaced. I also tried `(add-to-list 'bdf-directory-list ...)` to add the folder of the font file as well as using `create-fontset-from-fontset-spec` to setup a complete new fontset. This didn't work.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" #x3b1 "Fixed")`, without renaming the font? (You don't need to call `font-spec` in the `set-fontset-font` forms.) For me, in `emacs -Q`, `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" #x3b1 "DejaVu Sans Mono")` replaces the default Incosolata with DejaVu for "α". Considering also that `(set-fontset-font t #x3b1 (font-spec :family "FreeMono"))` works, I'd say there's something wrong with the font rather than with Emacs' setup.

Comment: Great! Actually I tried `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" #x3b1 "-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso10646-1")` and this is working out of the box! Maybe I did something wrong while trying to rename the font family. Thank a lot @ArchStanton :) !